# Why does java not exit the app on disposal?

Tags: java, swing, awt

I have the following problem: I want a swing window in java to be able to be shown and closed programatically. However I do not want to exit the app, when the frame is closed, as long as other windows are still open.

As far as I understand this is the intention of the `dispose()` method. Once all windows are disposed and no threads are running any more, the app should exit.

However I have the problem that my app does not exit at all. On further investigation I wrote a MWE and got the same behavior. I am nearly 100% sure that quite some time ago, when I did similar things, it worked as expected.

Do I need to write my own window manager?!? This seems stupid as java should have such functionality already. As far as I understand the docs it should work... I have not started any threads on my own and I think the frame should be disposed of if clicked the "X" or the button.

Can you point me to the problem?

```
package optimworkers.gui.config;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Test extends JFrame
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                new Test();
            }
        });
    }

    public Test()
    {
        JButton but = new JButton("Test");
        add(but);
        but.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                setVisible(false);
                dispose();
            }
        });

        pack();
        setVisible(true);

        setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    }

}
```

---

**Edit:**

I use Ubuntu Linux (Ubuntu 14.04 LTS to be correct). I tried both with OpenJDK 1.7.0_101 and 1.8.0_91 (both from the ubuntu repositories).

I intend to use java for this special project because of the JVM allowing to write portable code. Thus if it is not a real bug in the JRE, I must/shouold make sure, the app closes and issue a `System.exit(0);` call. However one reads this to be bad practice. I tried to avoid such till now at all costs.

Comment: have you tried `setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE)`

Comment: `As far as I understand this is the intention of the dispose() method`  - that is my understanding as well and it works fine for me using JDK 7 on Window7. That is I click on the button and a second of so later the JVM closes. I execute my code from the command line. Maybe it is a version/platform issue. Include you version/platform in the question and maybe others using the same will test and report the results.

Answer (score -2):

In order to dispose your current class(form) and open another one, you can use the following code. In order to exit your application, use `System.exit(0)`

```
       java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                dispose();
                new YOURCLASSTOBEOPENED().setVisible(true);
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(YOURCURRENTCLASS.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    });
```